# The name SPContext does not exist in the current context

Tags: c#, count

I'm new in creating a visual web part for Sharepoint 2010 and i'm actually trying to create a new visual web part in visual studio to get the count of my "person and group column" in my sharepoint project. I found this on the web and edited the values to suit my project. However, the system keep giving me this error "The name 'SPContext' does not exist in the current context".

here is my code:

```
using System;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts;

namespace CountingNoOfAttendee.VisualWebPart1
{
    public partial class VisualWebPart1UserControl : UserControl
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnInit(e);
            display1 = new Label();
        }

        protected override void CreateChildControls()
        {
            Controls.Add(display1);
            try
            {
                var list = SPContext.Current.Web.Lists.TryGetList("Register training");
                var items = list.Items;
                foreach (SPListItem item in items)
                {
                    var userColumn = item["Attendees"];
                    var users = userColumn as SPFieldUserValueCollection;
                    display1.Text = string.Format(display1.Text.Title,(users == null?0 : users.Count));
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                display1.Text = string.Format("An error occurred:", e.Message);
            }
            base.CreateChildControls();
        }
    }
}
```

Help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: The compiler doesn't know what SPContext is. Add a proper namespace with using keyword first.

Answer (score 3):

Add "using **Microsoft.SharePoint**;"

or

simply call "**Microsoft.SharePoint.SPContext.Current.Web.Url**"

Annoying that it's not added automatically!